# How to parametrize a function call in bash without using eval?

Tags: bash

I have the following code (simplified):

```
if ! sudo -u user command1 "$Options" -o1 -o2 2>>"$log" > "$Dir"/output;
```

However, in some cases (determined at run time, if a variable docker is set to true), I instead want to execute

```
if ! docker exec -t "$cont" command2 "$Options" -o1 -o2 2>>"$log" > "$Dir"/output;
```

What changes is the way to call the command (1 or 2). The rest of the parameters remain the same.

So I'd like to parametrize the call to command1 or command2.

Something like

```
if $docker then;
  Command = docker exec -t "$cont" command2
else
  Command = sudo -u user command1

if ! $Command "$Options" -o1 -o2 2>>"$log" > "$Dir"/output;
```

This does not work. Is it possible to achieve what I want without resorting to `eval`, which I understood to be a bad practice ?

Thanks

Comment: Use an array instead?

Comment: How do I "call" an array though? These are not just arguments, it's the command as well... In [this help](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), it seems to only mention the case where you need to parametrize arguments, but I need to parametrize the function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array to hold the command-specific part, and rely on word splitting to build the entire command line to run. Something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set up your assorted variables used below

if $docker; then
  cmd=(docker exec -t "$cont" command2)
else
  cmd=(sudo -u user command1)
fi

if ! "${cmd[@]}" "$Options" -o1 -o2 2>>"$log" > "$Dir"/output; then
# etc.
fi
```

Comment: omg I was so close I didn't know arrays would work for commands instead of just arguments. Thanks.

Comment: So just to clarify, this is better than the eval alternative, right ? How is it though (without going into too much details), since in the end it seems there's a string injection in both cases ?

Comment: Yeah, it's better than eval. Makes it harder to double-evaluate variables.